# Why text messages are not shown on other messaging apps, after I set my app as a default messaging app?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

If I set my app as a default messaging app, all incoming messages are not shown on other message apps. Here is my SmsReceiver and manifest.

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Object[] smsExtra = (Object[]) intent.getExtras().get("pdus");
    String body = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < smsExtra.length; ++i) {
        SmsMessage sms = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) smsExtra[i]);
        body += sms.getMessageBody();
    }

    Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(context)
            .setContentText(body)
            .setContentTitle("New Message")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_alert)
            .setStyle(new Notification.BigTextStyle().bigText(body))
            .build();
    NotificationManagerCompat notificationManagerCompat = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context);
    notificationManagerCompat.notify(1, notification);
}


<receiver
            android:name=".SmsReceiver"
            android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:exported="true" >
            <intent-filter android:priority="0" >
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_DELIVER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

A message is just shown as a notification and then it is not listed on other messaging app. Actually, I just want to set my app as default only to send MMS, so I don't want to handle incoming messages by my app.

Thank you.

Comment: `Here is my SmsReceiver and manifest file.` Where is the manifest you have said? Edit your question.

Comment: woops I just posted.

Comment: The default app is responsible for writing all incoming SMS to the Provider. It's also responsible for all incoming MMS, too. If your app is the default, it has to be pretty much a full-blown messaging app.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. But why did my app intercepts all messages coming and not shown on other message apps?

Comment: Those other apps are apparently reading messages from the SMS Provider - the central store for SMS messages. Since the default app is responsible for saving new incoming messages to the Provider, if you don't do it while your app is the default, then those messages just don't get saved there, and the other apps can't read them.

Comment: oh! So in order to make others to read, I need to save incoming messages to the provider! thanks much.

Comment: Mike, you are right! it works! thanks

Answer (score 0):

Updated receiver as below. it works

public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Object[] smsExtra = (Object[]) intent.getExtras().get("pdus");
    String body = "";
    String msg_from = "";
    SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
    msgs = new SmsMessage[smsExtra.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < smsExtra.length; ++i) {
        SmsMessage sms = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) smsExtra[i]);
        msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])smsExtra[i]);
        msg_from = msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
        body += sms.getMessageBody();
    }
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("address", msg_from);//sender name
    values.put("body", body);
    context.getContentResolver().insert(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"), values);
    Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(context)
            .setContentText(body)
            .setContentTitle(msg_from)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_alert)
            .setStyle(new Notification.BigTextStyle().bigText(body))
            .build();
    NotificationManagerCompat notificationManagerCompat = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context);
    notificationManagerCompat.notify(1, notification);
}
```

}